# Show function is continuous with respect to metric space

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Show that the function $Ψ: (X,d_\infty) → (R,d),$ defined by $Ψ(f ) = \arctan(f (3/4))$ is continuous.

When $d_∞(f , g ) = \max_{x∈[0,1]}|f (x)− g (x)|$ and $d$ is the standard metric on $R$, i.e., $d(x,y)=|x-y|$

I know that arctan is freely continuous and that I'm meant to use that fact? but I'm unsure how to start it

Comment: What is X? C[0,1]?

Comment: Sorry, yes X=(C[0,1],R) where obviously R is real numbers

Comment: I also suggest writing $d_\infty$, using {} when there are multiple signs in the subscript (for example $max_{x \in [0,1]}$) and using $\mathbb{R}$ to denote the set of real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\phi : (C[0,1], d_\infty) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R} ,d)$ as $\phi (f)= f(\frac{3}{4})$.
$\phi$ is continuous because $$d(\phi (f), \phi (g))=|f(\frac{3}{4})-g(\frac{3}{4})| \leq \max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|=d_\infty(f,g).$$

Now $\Psi =\arctan \circ \phi$, so $\Psi$ is continuous as composition of two continuous functions.